# Why won't my JS code filter out this "_" element from string?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on the FreeCodeCamp Front End Development Certification and have arrived at the Basic Algorithm Scripting part. One of the exercises is to write a code that tests for palindromes. I understand everything (well almost) that is to be done, have quickly written my code but cannot understand why it doesn't give the correct result for strings containting underscores (_). Here is my code:

```
function palindrome(str) {
    str = str.replace(/\W/g,'');
    if ((((str.toLowerCase()).split("")).reverse()).join("") == str.toLowerCase()){ 
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
palindrome("_eye");
```

Comment: Which part of your code you think that *should* filter out the underscore?

Comment: This '(/\W/g,'')' part, or so I thought. It's okay though. I've already got the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\W` in regex is basically a short way to write "every chat that is **not** any of the `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` chars".
As you you can see - digits and underscore are also part of that.

If you to remove every char that is not `[a-zA-Z]` you can use `/[^a-zA-Z]/` instead:

```js
function palindrome(str) {
    str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,'');
    if ((((str.toLowerCase()).split("")).reverse()).join("") == str.toLowerCase()){ 
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
console.log(palindrome("_eye"))
```

Comment: Will appreciate if the downvoter will leave a comment regarding the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

Just change yout regex to `str.replace(/[\W_]/g,'');`

Comment: This will merely suppress all letters and digits from the given string! (so most of the time returning `true` for any entry)

Comment: cFreed is right. I already tried that but it only resulted in 'true' being returned for almost all cases. The other poster's solution, with a slight tweak to exclude numeric elements from being filtered out, worked. Thank you all, nonetheless.